# How to extract a specific data range from multiple sheets in excel

Tags: excel, range

I have an excel sheet with four additional sheets

```
sheet1
sheet2
sheet3
summary (sheet4)
```

The first three sheets have a column of age. At the summary sheet i want to age data as age group ( 18 to 25, 26 to 33 etc..). I know how to get age group range from single sheet, but don't know how to get (exmp:18 to 25 from sheet1+sheet2+sheet3)a range from multiple sheet.
Please try to understand my question and please answer without VB code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply,
 But I got the solution with very easy formula.
1. Select the column "Age" and define name e.g ageA and repeat this on other sheets. Now there are three age columns with defined name Like ageA, ageB, ageC
2. at the summary sheet select an empty cell.
3. Enter this formula
  =COUNTSIFS(ageA,">=18",ageA,"<=26")+COUNTIFS(ageB,">=18",ageB,"<=26")+COUNTIFS(ageC,">=18",ageC<"=26")

This is work for me very accurate.

Answer (score -1):

You should refer to this link:

[Microsoft Excel Help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-PivotTable-report-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5)

Go to a blank sheet in your workbook

Consolidate data by using multiple page fields
You can create multiple page fields and assign your own item names for each source range. This lets you create partial or full consolidations; for example, one page field that consolidates Marketing and Sales apart from Manufacturing, and another page field that consolidates all three departments. To create a consolidation that uses multiple page fields, do the following:

Click a blank cell in the workbook that is not part of a PivotTable report.

To start the PivotTable and PivotChart Wizard, press ALT+D+P.

To add the PivotTable and PivotChart Wizard to the Quick Access Toolbar, do the following:

Click the arrow next to the toolbar and then click More Commands.

Under Choose commands from, select All Commands.

In the list, select PivotTable and PivotChart Wizard, click Add, and then click OK.

On the Step 1 page of the wizard, click Multiple consolidation ranges, and then click Next.

On the Step 2a page of the wizard, click I will create the page fields, and then click Next.

On the Step 2b page of the wizard, do the following:

For each cell range, click Collapse Dialog  Button image to temporarily hide the dialog box, select the cell range on the worksheet, press Expand Dialog  Button image , and then click Add.

If the cell range is in another workbook, open the workbook first to make it easier to make select the data.

Under How many page fields do you want?, click the number of page fields that you want to use.

Under What item labels do you want each page field to use to identify the selected data range?, for each page field, select the cell range, and then enter a name for that range.

Example

If you selected 1 under How many page fields do you want?, select each range, and then enter a different name in the Field One box. If you have four ranges and each one corresponds to a different quarter of the fiscal year, select the first range, enter Q1, select the second range, enter Q2, and repeat the process for Q3 and Q4.

If you selected 2 under How many page fields do you want?, do the same as the previous example in the Field one box. Then, select two ranges, and enter the same name, such as H1 and H2, in the Field two box. Select the first range, enter H1, select the second range, enter H1, select the third range, enter H2, select the fourth range, and then enter H2.

Click Next.

On the Step 3 page of the wizard, select a location for the PivotTable report, and then click Finish.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks for reply, this method make me confused. i got the solution, see my answer........ Regards